# MVC Html helper or partial view to reusable buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html-helper

I have a button type that designed with bootstrap classes and I want to do this reusable.

My Edit Button

```
        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.Id})" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
        </a>
```

My Delete Button

```
        <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new {id = item.Id})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
       </a>
```

How can I do this format as reusable. With partials or with HtmlHelpers? Is there any sample?

Comment: Either way will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ Stephen suggested you can use both,You can create a `HTML Helpers` by using the below code

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{

public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
{

    public static MvcHtmlString BootStarpDeleteHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string action)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        sb.Append("<a href=" + action + " class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>");
        sb.Append("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>");
        sb.Append("</a>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());  
    }

}
```

}

in the main view you can call the html helper like this

```
@Html.BootStarpDeleteHelper("#");
```

Else you can also create a partial view in the  Shared folder and  create a new partial view with name `_BootStarpDelete`

The view look like this

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new {id = item.Id})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</a>
```

In the main view you can render like this

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_BootStarpDelete")
```

Hope the above explanation will help you.If you want a single `html helper` for both `edit` and `delete` you need to pass `classes` as parameters.If the same if you want to do the `partial view` way then you have to pass a `model` with appropriate value such as `action and classes`